# Split tests file when using github actions parallel

Tags: github, integration-testing, circleci, github-actions

I am actually using circle ci to launch my behat tests through docker.

I want to migrate to github actions for cost reasons but i can't find any clue on how i can split my files on github actions when using parallel build.

Here is the command i am using to split my files on circleCI: `circleci tests glob "features/**/*.feature" | circleci tests split --split-by=filesize`.

Is there any existing command to do it appart from using knapsack pro which i can't use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [split_tests](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/split_tests), a tool similar to `circleci tests glob`.

It has the same set of features: split files according to filename, lines count or timing of a previous test result.

You'll probably need to configure your Github-Actions `ci.yml` to:

1. Download a binary release of `split_tests`
2. Create a `matrix` with a number of nodes,
3. For each node, run the tests using the split_tests partial files list,
4. (Optionally) Save the JUnit test report to a cache, to re-use it in the next run for timing.